# Is there a good online course for working with sklearn MLPClassifier?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I'am implementing an App for which I need a neural network. Because: I want to classify each DOM-text-element of an webpage which conains any curriculum vitae of a person. The neural network should be able to classify each DOM-text-element then if it is e.g. the name of the person, the birthday of the person, the last studies of the person, ... or only noise.

I want to use for this issue the sklearn MLPClassifier in python. But I neeed much more knowledge in:

a) which data should the feature vector contain (CSS properties, ...))

b) how many data  I need

c) which parameters needs the MLPClassfier for the best result (or only at least working)

Does anybody know a good online course where I cann get a better understanding of these things?

Comment: Have you checked udacity? I don't remember the name, it was intro to machine learning or something.

Comment: Have you attempted this without a NN? MLPClassifier seems overkill for something that could potentially be solved with a regex and a good idea of where the things you want occur in a CV.

Comment: I want to do this on any website in the web, independent of any language, structure, etc... I think this is only possible with machine learning right?